# FirebaseSimpleLogin: An unknown error occured. Only on android phone

Tags: android, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I have a mobile app built using ionic framework. It uses firebase + angularjs api extensively. I am using the api for facebook authentication. I have all the setup on Forge. Infact, the whole login process works well when I run the app on my browser(chrome). However when I install it on my phone, the authentication fails throwing the error mentioned in the subject. I tinkered with the whitelist in Forge as well to no avail. Any idea whats going on?

The API call throwing the error is `$scope.loginObj.$login('facebook')`

Comment: Can you provide more information? (a) Which version of the client are you using, (b) when are you instantiating the `FirebaseSimpleLogin` client in your app, and (c) when does the error occurin the flow (i.e. before the redirect, after the redirect, etc.)?

Comment: (a)firebase-simple-login.js#1.5.0. However I also tried with versions 1.4.0, 1.4.1 (b) I have a login button in my header. When user clicks on it, a method gets called in my angularjs controller that calls the regular code as mentioned here:https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html (c) The code pops up a white screen and I could see the error in the weinre debugger. I also tried setting preferRedirect to true. Note that everything works fine in the browser.

Comment: I am using cordova along with my ionic fwk. I have the InAppBrowser plugin installed.

Comment: Rob, I changed preferRedirect to true, and I can see this error now on my phone after the white popup . My phone is connected to the internet. Looks like the authentication has succeeded but the call back is failing. http://tinypic.com/r/358csb4/8

Comment: We've published a blog post which will help with setup and some of the gotchas: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-25-ionic-simple-login.html